# C# Winforms прокрутка ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, mousewheel

Как запретить прокрутку в ComboBox, когда курсор находится над ним и при этом **продолжать прокручивать главную форму**. Дело в том, что при выборе элементов у меня создаются метки и это не очень удобно, когда при прокрутке основного контента курсор мыши случайно попадает на ComboBox.

```
private void comboBox1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{ 
     ((HandledMouseEventArgs)e).Handled = true; 
     // Прокручивать главную форму...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Попробуй this.OnMouseWheel(e)

```
private void comboBox1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{ 
     ((HandledMouseEventArgs)e).Handled = true; 
     this.OnMouseWheel(e)
}
```